# Why transparent object altering only the phase of light but not the frequency or amplitude? Is there exception?

Tags: optics, phase-transition, microscopy

I have learned the fascinating phase contrast microscope from Eugene's textbook *optics* that made transparent object become visible.
From page 647, he said that

> In contradistinction, it is often desirable to “see” phase objects, that is, ones that are transparent, thereby providing practically no contrast with their environs and altering only the phase of the detected wave.

I am wondering, why transparent object only alter phase but not frequency or amplitude of light? Do transparent objects that altering frequency or amplitude of light exist in real life?

Comment: This is more or less the definition of the word transparent